# How to make anthy type unicode characters?

Tags: ibus

Windows japanese IME supports http://www.tofugu.com/2010/07/05/typing-japanese-special-characters/ typing special keywords to get some unicode chars. I miss this feature, and I want something simular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is such a feature in any of the Anthy engines available for Ubuntu, but I think it's worth mentioning that you can use [code points](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#ctrlshiftu) to type Unicode characters.